# Is it possible to use agile scrum with TFS?

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum

We're using TFS Work Items to manage our bugs and work items.

Would that be possible to use TFS for agile scrum project management? e.g. defining user stores, drawing burn down chart and cumulative chart, etc?

How?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely yes.

Generate a new Team Project choosing the default process template (MSF for Agile Software Development 5.0) during the Wizard execution.

Now within this new Team Project a great deal of ready-baked reports is available, 'agile' work-item type User Story as well. 
Out-of-the-box sprint planning is also quite nicely delivered.

With a small time-investment for orientation, customizing & tailoring to your own needs should be possible.

A very comprehensive [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/aaronbjork/scrum-with-tfs-2010) by A.Bjork was really helpful for me.

Comment: You can also download third-party Process Templates that concentrate on different features r implement them differently. I propose googling for "TFS TeamProject ProcessTemplate SCRUM" and looking at some templates before deciding on the one to use.

Comment: also see what the team is doing in TFS vNext: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-793T. YOu can try it yourself at http://tfspreview.com